# springboot 3 graalvm native image stuck forever: mac m1

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am using spring boot 3.0.2 and I am using native-maven-plugin.

```
 <plugin>
       <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
       <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>0.9.19</version>
 </plugin>
```

when I try to build a graalvm native image with this command

```
./mvnw -Pnative spring-boot:build-image
```

The process runs for a while and then it is just waiting at this stage forever.

```
[INFO]     [creator]         Executing native-image -H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC @/workspace/META-INF/native-image/argfile -H:Name=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/com.example.spring6.Spring6Application -cp /workspace:/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.4.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.4.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.19.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.6.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-web-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-observation-1.10.3.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-commons-1.10.3.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactor-netty-http-1.1.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-http-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-handler-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-http2-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-dns-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-dns-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-dns-native-macos-4.1.87.Final-osx-x86_64.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.87.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactor-netty-core-1.1.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-socks-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webflux-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jcl-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-3.0.2.jar com.example.spring6.Spring6Application
```

I am using macbook pro m1. My java version

```
openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.1 (build 17.0.6+10-jvmci-22.3-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.3.1 (build 17.0.6+10-jvmci-22.3-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the output of the `native-image` command somehow? Or you might want to run it manually from terminal and see what happens

Comment: sorry I do not understand. What exactly do you mean?I am running this command from the terminal `./mvnw -Pnative spring-boot:build-image`

Comment: Your log contains "Executing native-image ..." and what follows is full command line for the native-image invocation that hangs. You might want to copy and run it from your terminal and capture output, that might give some insights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr - update your pom.xml to use a different Buildpacks image that properly supports ARM64:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <builder>dashaun/builder:tiny</builder>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The other answer correctly explains how to build a native image, but it does not solve your problem if you wanted to containerize your application - tricky to do as the native image is created for your local host architecture, and would not work if you just copy it to a standard base image. It also requires a local installation of the GraalVM build tools.

The Spring Boot plugin is solving this problem by building your project in a container, using [Buildpacks](https://buildpacks.io/). Unfortunately, the default Packeto Buildpacks image does not support the Mac M1 architecture ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-GraalVM#building-container-images)). Instead, use [this base image](https://github.com/dashaun/paketo-arm64) and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of [Itay Polack-Gadassi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75743604/21545743) worked perfectly for me which is why I want to expand on it to include the Gradle version.

To build a native image with Gradle, the task `bootBuildImage` is used.
However, the default buildpack image used does not support ARM architectures, resulting in builds running forever with no real error message.

To solve this problem, another buildpack image has to be configured as described in [this repo](https://github.com/dashaun/paketo-arm64).

For Groovy `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.named("bootBuildImage") {
    builder = "dashaun/builder:tiny"
    environment = ["BP_NATIVE_IMAGE" : "true"]
}
```

For Kotlin `build.gradle.kts` (including OS & CPU check):

```kotlin
tasks.withType<BootBuildImage> {
    val osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase()
    val arch = System.getProperty("os.arch")

    val runningOnM1Mac = "mac" in osName && arch == "aarch64"
    if (runningOnM1Mac) {
        builder.set("dashaun/builder:tiny")
        environment.set(mapOf("BP_NATIVE_IMAGE" to "true"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For native image command is `mvn -Pnative native:compile`

> With the native profile active, you can invoke the native:compile goal to trigger native-image compilation:

> $ mvn -Pnative native:compile

> The native image executable can be found in the target directory.

[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#native-image.developing-your-first-application.native-build-tools.maven)

The command you used is `spring-boot:build-image` which is generating docker image and running the native image under docker. if that command is stucking at some point it means docker is not responding or something freezing that side. Check this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#native-image.advanced.converting-executable-jars.buildpacks) for further details.

Last note please do not use version number in native-maven-plugin plugin. pom should look like [this](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=native)

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
```