# Build of native image with Spring Boot get stuck on Apple Silicon

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, spring-native

The build with `-Pnative` starts and progresses successfully, but fails to complete on my Apple Silicon Mac. Any ideas what might be missing?

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.2)

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ bef-projekt-aggregat ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/work/IdeaProjects/wrwks/bef/bef-projekt-aggregat/target/bef-projekt-aggregat-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.2:repackage (repackage) @ bef-projekt-aggregat ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot:3.0.2:build-image (default-cli) < package @ bef-projekt-aggregat <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.2:build-image (default-cli) @ bef-projekt-aggregat ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/bef-projekt-aggregat:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:7f1dc12643a7d5c43d1eaa88b443099c7639e5e54a7711593fe8fa7a5929bd2f'
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:tiny-cnb' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:11d6196c9185cbb5eff12410ebc14ad5a19edc6553329b5d3d2ae7a95ed723f9'
[INFO]  > Pulling buildpack image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/graalvm:latest' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled buildpack image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/graalvm@sha256:a4713efaccb92123f7b58ef0426d6102276964583a4035c0fc62ba1ae5817d6e'
[INFO]  > Pulling buildpack image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image:latest' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled buildpack image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image@sha256:2bfd09f5349a9cfe574d16e8f55b11d33a02f6bde5237ab13c755a8d7051d356'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.16.0
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-04b0171c77cc.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Previous image with name "docker.io/library/bef-projekt-aggregat:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     8 of 15 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/graalvm               7.10.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates       3.5.1
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica     9.10.3
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft                  1.24.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar        6.6.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot           5.22.1
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/native-image          5.8.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables 4.4.0
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for GraalVM 7.10.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/graalvm
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must be omitted)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              19.*                                                         the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 19.* from BP_JVM_VERSION
[INFO]     [creator]       GraalVM JDK 19.0.2: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-22.3.1/graalvm-ce-java19-linux-amd64-22.3.1.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Expanding to /layers/paketo-buildpacks_graalvm/nik
[INFO]     [creator]         Warning: The JVM cacerts entries cannot be loaded with Java 18+, for more information see: https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/libjvm/issues/158
[INFO]     [creator]       GraalVM Native Image Substrate VM 19.0.2
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-22.3.1/native-image-installable-svm-java19-linux-amd64-22.3.1.jar
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Installing substrate VM
[INFO]     [creator]     Processing Component archive: /tmp/61411f4edce57666c2ecd535aa71f970dec8ab4becf7f23b322845009e02ddab/native-image-installable-svm-java19-linux-amd64-22.3.1.jar
[INFO]     [creator]     Installing new component: Native Image (org.graalvm.native-image, version 22.3.1)
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/JAVA_HOME.override
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/JDK_HOME.override
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: BOM table is deprecated in this buildpack api version, though it remains supported for backwards compatibility. Buildpack authors should write BOM information to <layer>.sbom.<ext>, launch.sbom.<ext>, or build.sbom.<ext>.
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: BOM table is deprecated in this buildpack api version, though it remains supported for backwards compatibility. Buildpack authors should write BOM information to <layer>.sbom.<ext>, launch.sbom.<ext>, or build.sbom.<ext>.
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: BOM table is deprecated in this buildpack api version, though it remains supported for backwards compatibility. Buildpack authors should write BOM information to <layer>.sbom.<ext>, launch.sbom.<ext>, or build.sbom.<ext>.
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.5.1
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Syft 1.24.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/syft
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/anchore/syft/releases/download/v0.69.1/syft_0.69.1_linux_amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/SYFT_CHECK_FOR_APP_UPDATE.default
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Executable JAR 6.6.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar
[INFO]     [creator]       Class Path: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.delim
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.prepend
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Spring Boot 5.22.1
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED   false  whether to contribute Spring Boot cloud bindings support
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED  false  whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_ENABLED   true   Deprecated - whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
[INFO]     [creator]       Class Path: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         native args file /workspace/META-INF/native-image/argfile
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS_FILE.default
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.append
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.delim
[INFO]     [creator]       Image labels:
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.title
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.version
[INFO]     [creator]         org.springframework.boot.version
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: BOM table is deprecated in this buildpack api version, though it remains supported for backwards compatibility. Buildpack authors should write BOM information to <layer>.sbom.<ext>, launch.sbom.<ext>, or build.sbom.<ext>.
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Native Image 5.8.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/native-image
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_BINARY_COMPRESSION_METHOD                                                    Compression mechanism used to reduce binary size. Options: `none` (default), `upx` or `gzexe`
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE                       true                                      enable native image build
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS                                                 arguments to pass to the native-image command
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS_FILE  /workspace/META-INF/native-image/argfile  a file with arguments to pass to the native-image command
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILT_ARTIFACT                                                  the built application artifact explicitly, required if building from a JAR
[INFO]     [creator]       Native Image: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Executing native-image -H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC @/workspace/META-INF/native-image/argfile -H:Name=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/at.wrwks.bef.projektaggregat.ApplicationKt -cp /workspace:/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/annotations-13.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-reflect-1.8.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.6.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-reactor-1.6.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-reactive-1.6.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.8.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.8.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-module-kotlin-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactor-kotlin-extensions-1.1.7.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.19.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.6.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jcl-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-actuator-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-observation-1.10.3.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-commons-1.10.3.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-core-1.10.3.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactor-netty-http-1.1.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-http-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-http2-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-dns-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-dns-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-dns-native-macos-4.1.87.Final-osx-x86_64.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.87.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/reactor-netty-core-1.1.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-web-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webflux-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-messaging-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-integration-core-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-integration-jmx-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-retry-2.0.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-cloud-function-context-4.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/typetools-0.6.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-cloud-function-core-4.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-4.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-integration-kafka-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-kafka-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-4.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kafka-streams-3.3.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/rocksdbjni-7.1.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.10.3.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/simpleclient_common-0.16.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/simpleclient-0.16.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/simpleclient_tracer_otel-0.16.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/simpleclient_tracer_common-0.16.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/simpleclient_tracer_otel_agent-0.16.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-config-6.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-crypto-6.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-oauth2-core-6.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/sentry-logback-6.11.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/sentry-6.11.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.4.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.4.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-test-1.6.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-test-jvm-1.6.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-6.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-handler-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-socks-4.1.87.Final.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-3.0.2.jar at.wrwks.bef.projektaggregat.ApplicationKt
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355506/springboot-3-graalvm-native-image-stuck-forever-mac-m1) might help

Comment: I dont see an error in the logs, for the native-image command its possible to add a --verbose and --fallback=false flags, the native compile can use a lot of memory